# Conditional In For-Loop Escapes Sub

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

My code is as follows:

```
sub main()   

'''some more code'''

For j = InStr(1, stext, " ") To Len(stext)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(stext, j, 1)) Or IsAlpha(Mid(stext, j, 1)) Then
            letter1 = Mid(stext, j, Len(stext))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

'''some more code'''

end sub
```

As I walk through the macro, when it gets to this line:

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(stext, j, 1)) Or IsAlpha(Mid(stext, j, 1)) Then
```

it escapes the entire sub!

What am I doing wrong, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help.

[ISALPHA, ISNUMERIC? - Microsoft Access / VBA Answers](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/207974-isalpha-isnumeric)

Answer (score 3):

This typically happens when you have an error.  In this case, it could be an out of bounds error.  You could have a space at the end of `stext`, which would cause this problem.

Comment: its escaping the for loop on the first try

Comment: put On Error Goto 0 statement before For loop, and it will show you an error

Comment: Could be IsAlpha, I don't think that's a build in VBA function.